# How to iterate over JSON files in a directory and upload to mongodb

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, mongodb, pymongo

So I have a folder with about 500 JSON files. I need to upload all of them to a local mongodb database. I tried using Mongo Compass, but Compass can only upload one file at a time. In python I tried to write some simple code to iterate through the folder and upload them one by one, but I ran into some problems. First of all the JSON files are not comma-separated, rather line separated. So the files look like:

```
{ some JSON object }
{ some JSON object }
...
```

I wrote the following code to iterate through the folder and upload it:

```
import pymongo
import json 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient['Test']
mycol = mydb['data']

directory = os.fsencode("C:/Users/PB/Desktop/test/")

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".json"):
        mycol.insert_many(filename)
```

The code basically goes through a folder, checks if it's a .json file, then inserts it into the database. That is what should happen. However, I get this error:

> TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON,
>   bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from
>   collections.MutableMapping

I cannot seem to upload it through python. I tried multiple variations of the code, but for some reason the python does not accept the json files. 
The problem with these files seems to be that python only allows for comma-separated JSON files.
How could I fix this to upload all the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're inserting the names of the files to mongo. Not the contents of the file.

Assuming you have multiple json files in a directory, where each file contains a json-object in each line...

You need to go through all the files, filter them, open them, read them line by line, parse each line into a dict, and then insert. Something like below:

```
os.chdir(directory)
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file.endswith(".json"):
        with open(file) as f:
             for line in f:
                 mongo_obj = json.loads(line)
                 mycol.insert(mongo_obj)
```

I did a `chdir` first to avoid having to pass the whole path to `open`

Comment: Nevermind, I tweaked a bit and it works. Thank you! I do however have some files which have bad JSON objects and get "JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 3471 (char 3470)". You know how I could skip those objects?

Comment: try-except around the parsing call, catch that error and ignore it with a `continue`. I would suggest logging the exception as well.